# WTSEnumerateSessions hangs and never returns

Tags: c#, windows, session, service

I have a .Net service written in c#. I am pInvoking `WTSEnumerateSessions`. The session checking is run by a timer every 15 minutes, it lists all sessions and compares the username/domain combination against a predefined set of users to determine if they are logged in on the server or not.

The problem is with a couple of servers the call to `WTSEnumerateSessions` hangs indefinitely. It works fine for a couple of times and then all of a sudden it stops and it is causing the service to become unresponsive.

Here is the code that I use to enumerate the sessions.

```
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
       IntPtr hServer,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
       ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

 [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
 static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

 [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
 static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
        System.IntPtr hServer,
        int sessionId, 
        WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, 
        out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, 
        out uint pBytesReturned);

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
 {
      public Int32 SessionID;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public String pWinStationName;

      public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
 }

 public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
 {
      WTSInitialProgram,
      WTSApplicationName,
      WTSWorkingDirectory,
      WTSOEMId,
      WTSSessionId,
      WTSUserName,
      WTSWinStationName,
      WTSDomainName,
      WTSConnectState,
      WTSClientBuildNumber,
      WTSClientName,
      WTSClientDirectory,
      WTSClientProductId,
      WTSClientHardwareId,
      WTSClientAddress,
      WTSClientDisplay,
      WTSClientProtocolType
 }

 public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
 {
      WTSActive,
      WTSConnected,
      WTSConnectQuery,
      WTSShadow,
      WTSDisconnected,
      WTSIdle,
      WTSListen,
      WTSReset,
      WTSDown,
      WTSInit
  }

 private void ListUsers_Elapsed()
 {
      IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
      List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
      serverHandle = WTSOpenServer("");

      try
      {
        IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        Int32 sessionCount = 0;
        Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref                     sessionCount);
        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
        uint bytes = 0;

        if (retVal != 0)
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
          {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            currentSession += dataSize;

            WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
            WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);

            //Then I compare the session information against a list of users to determine if they are still active

            WTSFreeMemory(userPtr); 
            WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
          }

          WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        CloseServer(serverHandle);
      }

    }
```

I generated a user dump and it seems that there is a WaitForSingleObject that never times out:

```
00000000`cd78dd78 000007fe`fd6810dc ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
00000000`cd78dd80 000007fe`fce11442 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
00000000`cd78de20 000007fe`fce113fd winsta!WaitForLsmStart+0xa3
00000000`cd78de50 000007fe`fce11336 winsta!OpenLocalLSM+0xe0
00000000`cd78deb0 000007fe`fce12669 winsta!CPublicBinding::GetLSMBinding+0x51
00000000`cd78def0 000007fe`fce12576 winsta!_tsrpcEnumerate+0xd3
00000000`cd78df90 000007fe`fb073500 winsta!WinStationEnumerateW+0x22
00000000`cd78dfc0 000007fe`8de35caf wtsapi32!WTSEnumerateSessionsA+0x60
00000000`cd78e030 000007fe`8de351c0 0x000007fe`8de35caf
00000000`cd78e120 000007fe`8de34b61 0x000007fe`8de351c0
00000000`cd78e260 000007fe`8de3849a 0x000007fe`8de34b61
00000000`cd78e2d0 000007fe`eb922c73 0x000007fe`8de3849a
00000000`cd78e370 000007fe`ec2639a5 System_ni+0x922c73
00000000`cd78e3e0 000007fe`ec263719 mscorlib_ni+0x4a39a5
00000000`cd78e540 000007fe`ec30be92 mscorlib_ni+0x4a3719
00000000`cd78e570 000007fe`ec30bc7e mscorlib_ni+0x54be92
00000000`cd78e600 000007fe`ec2c12e4 mscorlib_ni+0x54bc7e
00000000`cd78e670 000007fe`ed45a7f3 mscorlib_ni+0x5012e4
00000000`cd78e710 000007fe`ed45a6de clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
00000000`cd78e750 000007fe`ed45ae76 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
00000000`cd78e790 000007fe`ed519033 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
00000000`cd78e940 000007fe`ed45c121 clr!AppDomainTimerCallback_Worker+0x23
00000000`cd78ea30 000007fe`ed45c0a8 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d
00000000`cd78ea70 000007fe`ed45c019 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
00000000`cd78eb70 000007fe`ed45c15f clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75
00000000`cd78ec00 000007fe`ed518fc1 clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
00000000`cd78ec60 000007fe`ed518f35 clr!AppDomainTimerCallback+0x66
00000000`cd78ecc0 000007fe`ed518b42 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion+0x36
00000000`cd78ed10 000007fe`ed4df046 clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x122
00000000`cd78edb0 000007fe`ed4def3a clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+0x46
00000000`cd78ede0 000007fe`ed59fcb6 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0xf4
00000000`cd78ee70 00000000`775f59ed clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000000`cd78f930 00000000`7772ba01 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`cd78f960 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Can someone please explain why it is hanging and if there is a better way to do this. My reason to rely on a timer instead of registering the `OnSessionChange` event is that in the past I found the latter unreliable as it sometimes fires bogus events or it never fires at all on a session change has occurred.

And as I said this is working fine on the majority of the servers except a couple of them. And even for those affected by the issue it works after the timer fires the elapsed event for the first 4 or 5 times and then it just hangs on the next raised elapsed event and the same goes for each consecutive elapsed event after that.

P.S. the servers affected all have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed

EDIT:

Ok I found something really weird. I managed to get WTSEnumerateSessions to work without hanging. The problem is what I did does not really make sense and in the life of me I cannot figure out what its doing to stop the hanging.

So here is what I did, out of frustration I was looking for other methods to get the sessions list. One of these methods was using `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` to get the list of sessions instead of `WTSEnumerateSessions`. So I called the following function right before calling `WTSEnumerateSessions`.

```
public static List<string> PopulateSessionsList()
        {
            var outList = new List<string>();
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            DateTime systime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); //win32 systemdate

            UInt64 count;
            IntPtr luidPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            CommonWin32.LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out count, out luidPtr);  //gets an array of pointers to LUIDs

            IntPtr iter = luidPtr;      //set the pointer to the start of the array

            for (ulong i = 0; i < count; i++)   //for each pointer in the array
            {
                IntPtr sessionData;

                CommonWin32.LsaGetLogonSessionData(iter, out sessionData);
                CommonWin32.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA data = (CommonWin32.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(sessionData, typeof(CommonWin32.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA));

                //if we have a valid logon
                if (data.PSiD != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    //get the security identifier for further use
                    System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(data.PSiD);

                    //extract some useful information from the session data struct
                    var ptrToStringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.Username.buffer);
                    if (ptrToStringUni != null)
                    {
                        string username = ptrToStringUni.Trim();          //get the account username
                        var toStringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.LoginDomain.buffer);
                        if (toStringUni != null)
                        {
                            string domain = toStringUni.Trim();        //domain for this account  
                            var stringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.AuthenticationPackage.buffer);
                            if (stringUni != null)
                            {
                                string authpackage = stringUni.Trim();    //authentication package
                            }
                            string session = data.Session.ToString();
                            CommonWin32.SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE secType = (CommonWin32.SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE)data.LogonType;
                            DateTime time = systime.AddTicks((long)data.LoginTime);                              //get the datetime the session was logged in

                            outList.Add("Session: " + session + " User: " + username + " *** Domain: " + domain + " *** Login Type: (" + data.LogonType + ") " + secType.ToString() + " *** Login Time: " + time.ToLocalTime().ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                iter = (IntPtr)((int)iter + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CommonWin32.LUID)));  //move the pointer forward
                CommonWin32.LsaFreeReturnBuffer(sessionData);   //free the SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA memory in the struct
            }
            CommonWin32.LsaFreeReturnBuffer(luidPtr);   //free the array of LUIDs

            return outList;
        }
```

And this is my pInvoke code:

```
[DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern uint LsaFreeReturnBuffer(IntPtr buffer);

[DllImport("Secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern uint LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out UInt64 LogonSessionCount, out IntPtr LogonSessionList);

[DllImport("Secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern uint LsaGetLogonSessionData(IntPtr luid, out IntPtr ppLogonSessionData);
```

To my surprise, calling this stopped the hanging issue. I am not sure why it did that. Not sure if it calls some internal/private method.

Without calling the new method it only takes less than 10 consecutive calls for the culprit to hang, this was always the case with every test I tried on several machines. With the added code, it just works. doesn't matter if you call `WTSEnumerateSessions` like 1000 times in a single minute it never hanged. Not even once.

So can someone tell me why calling `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` and `LsaGetLogonSessionData` magically stops the hanging. Any information on what these functions do internally?

Comment: Very few Google hits for WaitForLsmStart.  Just two, one of them describes your exact problem and the workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant I see the two answers, one is Firefox crash and the other is an issue with a printer update I believe. None of them offer any real solution. And I cannot go around ask users to not install updates. I need a real fix (workaround) for this.

Comment: You are not going to get a "real fix" from anybody but Microsoft.  If you are reluctant to call them then *advise* your customer about what you've discovered.  They can make their own decision about how to proceed.

Comment: @HansPassant recently I was able to reproduce the issue on my computer and I already uninstalled the KB in question. So there might be something else. Can it be a privilage or security issue?, i have tried many things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated my question with a new find that I accidentally stumbled upon while trying to figure out a way to stop my service from hanging. Any idea why calling the new method just before calling `WTSEnumerateSessions` magically stops the latter from hanging?