# How can I get current value of a Windows environment variable from a different session

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6.1

Using C# with .Net 4+ or Standard 2.0 or Windows API, I would like to get the value of an environment variable for all users that are logged in, let's call the variable "Identifier".  The variable for these sessions is set programmatically (by code I don't control) after they log in.  The "Identifier" can be different each time they log in.

How can I get the current value of the "Identifier" environment variable from a session other than the one my process is running under, or is it not possible?

Comment: You mean you want to get a local environment variable from a different Windows login session?

Comment: yes, I believe it would be considered a local environment variable.

Comment: I think [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/397977/434988) might be a starting point (basically you would look at `HKEY_USERS\Environment\Identifier`).

Comment: I don't believe this value is going to show up in the registry.  edit: I will investigate further though.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you don't have a System or User environment variable, so it seems unlikely you'll be able to retrieve it.

Comment: it's definitely an environment variable but it's not in registry (wrote program to check).  This is in a cloud environment managed by a 3rd party company.  My next step will be to see if I can get the environment variables of a specific process that is launched upon login where I know the environment variable in question is accessible.

Comment: You are oversimplifying the registry. Keys can be volatile, i.e. aren't written to disk. See [RegCreateKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexw), for example.

Comment: Even if it were a volatile key, wouldn't the registry search of HKU\{SID}\Environment have found it if it were a user environment variable?  It ended up being a process environment variable, do you know a place in registry those would be stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User environment variables are accessible under HKEY_USERS[SID]\Environment.  You can use the following to search for a specific environment variable:

(NOTE: Machine level variables are in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment.  The does not look for those.  Those should be available under the same session your process is running in so it's unrelated to the original quesion regarding session specific variables.)

Put following in a new class:

```
    static class WinApis
{        
    [DllImport("Secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern NtStatus LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out UInt64 LogonSessionCount, out IntPtr LogonSessionList);
    [DllImport("secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern NtStatus LsaFreeReturnBuffer([In] IntPtr buffer);

    [DllImport("Secur32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern uint LsaGetLogonSessionData(IntPtr luid, out IntPtr ppLogonSessionData);
    private enum NtStatus : uint
    {
        // Success
        Success = 0x00000000,
        Wait0 = 0x00000000,
        Wait1 = 0x00000001,
        Wait2 = 0x00000002,
        Wait3 = 0x00000003,
        Wait63 = 0x0000003f,
        Abandoned = 0x00000080,
        AbandonedWait0 = 0x00000080,
        AbandonedWait1 = 0x00000081,
        AbandonedWait2 = 0x00000082,
        AbandonedWait3 = 0x00000083,
        AbandonedWait63 = 0x000000bf,
        UserApc = 0x000000c0,
        KernelApc = 0x00000100,
        Alerted = 0x00000101,
        Timeout = 0x00000102,
        Pending = 0x00000103,
        Reparse = 0x00000104,
        MoreEntries = 0x00000105,
        NotAllAssigned = 0x00000106,
        SomeNotMapped = 0x00000107,
        OpLockBreakInProgress = 0x00000108,
        VolumeMounted = 0x00000109,
        RxActCommitted = 0x0000010a,
        NotifyCleanup = 0x0000010b,
        NotifyEnumDir = 0x0000010c,
        NoQuotasForAccount = 0x0000010d,
        PrimaryTransportConnectFailed = 0x0000010e,
        PageFaultTransition = 0x00000110,
        PageFaultDemandZero = 0x00000111,
        PageFaultCopyOnWrite = 0x00000112,
        PageFaultGuardPage = 0x00000113,
        PageFaultPagingFile = 0x00000114,
        CrashDump = 0x00000116,
        ReparseObject = 0x00000118,
        NothingToTerminate = 0x00000122,
        ProcessNotInJob = 0x00000123,
        ProcessInJob = 0x00000124,
        ProcessCloned = 0x00000129,
        FileLockedWithOnlyReaders = 0x0000012a,
        FileLockedWithWriters = 0x0000012b,

        // Informational
        Informational = 0x40000000,
        ObjectNameExists = 0x40000000,
        ThreadWasSuspended = 0x40000001,
        WorkingSetLimitRange = 0x40000002,
        ImageNotAtBase = 0x40000003,
        RegistryRecovered = 0x40000009,

        // Warning
        Warning = 0x80000000,
        GuardPageViolation = 0x80000001,
        DatatypeMisalignment = 0x80000002,
        Breakpoint = 0x80000003,
        SingleStep = 0x80000004,
        BufferOverflow = 0x80000005,
        NoMoreFiles = 0x80000006,
        HandlesClosed = 0x8000000a,
        PartialCopy = 0x8000000d,
        DeviceBusy = 0x80000011,
        InvalidEaName = 0x80000013,
        EaListInconsistent = 0x80000014,
        NoMoreEntries = 0x8000001a,
        LongJump = 0x80000026,
        DllMightBeInsecure = 0x8000002b,

        // Error
        Error = 0xc0000000,
        Unsuccessful = 0xc0000001,
        NotImplemented = 0xc0000002,
        InvalidInfoClass = 0xc0000003,
        InfoLengthMismatch = 0xc0000004,
        AccessViolation = 0xc0000005,
        InPageError = 0xc0000006,
        PagefileQuota = 0xc0000007,
        InvalidHandle = 0xc0000008,
        BadInitialStack = 0xc0000009,
        BadInitialPc = 0xc000000a,
        InvalidCid = 0xc000000b,
        TimerNotCanceled = 0xc000000c,
        InvalidParameter = 0xc000000d,
        NoSuchDevice = 0xc000000e,
        NoSuchFile = 0xc000000f,
        InvalidDeviceRequest = 0xc0000010,
        EndOfFile = 0xc0000011,
        WrongVolume = 0xc0000012,
        NoMediaInDevice = 0xc0000013,
        NoMemory = 0xc0000017,
        NotMappedView = 0xc0000019,
        UnableToFreeVm = 0xc000001a,
        UnableToDeleteSection = 0xc000001b,
        IllegalInstruction = 0xc000001d,
        AlreadyCommitted = 0xc0000021,
        AccessDenied = 0xc0000022,
        BufferTooSmall = 0xc0000023,
        ObjectTypeMismatch = 0xc0000024,
        NonContinuableException = 0xc0000025,
        BadStack = 0xc0000028,
        NotLocked = 0xc000002a,
        NotCommitted = 0xc000002d,
        InvalidParameterMix = 0xc0000030,
        ObjectNameInvalid = 0xc0000033,
        ObjectNameNotFound = 0xc0000034,
        ObjectNameCollision = 0xc0000035,
        ObjectPathInvalid = 0xc0000039,
        ObjectPathNotFound = 0xc000003a,
        ObjectPathSyntaxBad = 0xc000003b,
        DataOverrun = 0xc000003c,
        DataLate = 0xc000003d,
        DataError = 0xc000003e,
        CrcError = 0xc000003f,
        SectionTooBig = 0xc0000040,
        PortConnectionRefused = 0xc0000041,
        InvalidPortHandle = 0xc0000042,
        SharingViolation = 0xc0000043,
        QuotaExceeded = 0xc0000044,
        InvalidPageProtection = 0xc0000045,
        MutantNotOwned = 0xc0000046,
        SemaphoreLimitExceeded = 0xc0000047,
        PortAlreadySet = 0xc0000048,
        SectionNotImage = 0xc0000049,
        SuspendCountExceeded = 0xc000004a,
        ThreadIsTerminating = 0xc000004b,
        BadWorkingSetLimit = 0xc000004c,
        IncompatibleFileMap = 0xc000004d,
        SectionProtection = 0xc000004e,
        EasNotSupported = 0xc000004f,
        EaTooLarge = 0xc0000050,
        NonExistentEaEntry = 0xc0000051,
        NoEasOnFile = 0xc0000052,
        EaCorruptError = 0xc0000053,
        FileLockConflict = 0xc0000054,
        LockNotGranted = 0xc0000055,
        DeletePending = 0xc0000056,
        CtlFileNotSupported = 0xc0000057,
        UnknownRevision = 0xc0000058,
        RevisionMismatch = 0xc0000059,
        InvalidOwner = 0xc000005a,
        InvalidPrimaryGroup = 0xc000005b,
        NoImpersonationToken = 0xc000005c,
        CantDisableMandatory = 0xc000005d,
        NoLogonServers = 0xc000005e,
        NoSuchLogonSession = 0xc000005f,
        NoSuchPrivilege = 0xc0000060,
        PrivilegeNotHeld = 0xc0000061,
        InvalidAccountName = 0xc0000062,
        UserExists = 0xc0000063,
        NoSuchUser = 0xc0000064,
        GroupExists = 0xc0000065,
        NoSuchGroup = 0xc0000066,
        MemberInGroup = 0xc0000067,
        MemberNotInGroup = 0xc0000068,
        LastAdmin = 0xc0000069,
        WrongPassword = 0xc000006a,
        IllFormedPassword = 0xc000006b,
        PasswordRestriction = 0xc000006c,
        LogonFailure = 0xc000006d,
        AccountRestriction = 0xc000006e,
        InvalidLogonHours = 0xc000006f,
        InvalidWorkstation = 0xc0000070,
        PasswordExpired = 0xc0000071,
        AccountDisabled = 0xc0000072,
        NoneMapped = 0xc0000073,
        TooManyLuidsRequested = 0xc0000074,
        LuidsExhausted = 0xc0000075,
        InvalidSubAuthority = 0xc0000076,
        InvalidAcl = 0xc0000077,
        InvalidSid = 0xc0000078,
        InvalidSecurityDescr = 0xc0000079,
        ProcedureNotFound = 0xc000007a,
        InvalidImageFormat = 0xc000007b,
        NoToken = 0xc000007c,
        BadInheritanceAcl = 0xc000007d,
        RangeNotLocked = 0xc000007e,
        DiskFull = 0xc000007f,
        ServerDisabled = 0xc0000080,
        ServerNotDisabled = 0xc0000081,
        TooManyGuidsRequested = 0xc0000082,
        GuidsExhausted = 0xc0000083,
        InvalidIdAuthority = 0xc0000084,
        AgentsExhausted = 0xc0000085,
        InvalidVolumeLabel = 0xc0000086,
        SectionNotExtended = 0xc0000087,
        NotMappedData = 0xc0000088,
        ResourceDataNotFound = 0xc0000089,
        ResourceTypeNotFound = 0xc000008a,
        ResourceNameNotFound = 0xc000008b,
        ArrayBoundsExceeded = 0xc000008c,
        FloatDenormalOperand = 0xc000008d,
        FloatDivideByZero = 0xc000008e,
        FloatInexactResult = 0xc000008f,
        FloatInvalidOperation = 0xc0000090,
        FloatOverflow = 0xc0000091,
        FloatStackCheck = 0xc0000092,
        FloatUnderflow = 0xc0000093,
        IntegerDivideByZero = 0xc0000094,
        IntegerOverflow = 0xc0000095,
        PrivilegedInstruction = 0xc0000096,
        TooManyPagingFiles = 0xc0000097,
        FileInvalid = 0xc0000098,
        InstanceNotAvailable = 0xc00000ab,
        PipeNotAvailable = 0xc00000ac,
        InvalidPipeState = 0xc00000ad,
        PipeBusy = 0xc00000ae,
        IllegalFunction = 0xc00000af,
        PipeDisconnected = 0xc00000b0,
        PipeClosing = 0xc00000b1,
        PipeConnected = 0xc00000b2,
        PipeListening = 0xc00000b3,
        InvalidReadMode = 0xc00000b4,
        IoTimeout = 0xc00000b5,
        FileForcedClosed = 0xc00000b6,
        ProfilingNotStarted = 0xc00000b7,
        ProfilingNotStopped = 0xc00000b8,
        NotSameDevice = 0xc00000d4,
        FileRenamed = 0xc00000d5,
        CantWait = 0xc00000d8,
        PipeEmpty = 0xc00000d9,
        CantTerminateSelf = 0xc00000db,
        InternalError = 0xc00000e5,
        InvalidParameter1 = 0xc00000ef,
        InvalidParameter2 = 0xc00000f0,
        InvalidParameter3 = 0xc00000f1,
        InvalidParameter4 = 0xc00000f2,
        InvalidParameter5 = 0xc00000f3,
        InvalidParameter6 = 0xc00000f4,
        InvalidParameter7 = 0xc00000f5,
        InvalidParameter8 = 0xc00000f6,
        InvalidParameter9 = 0xc00000f7,
        InvalidParameter10 = 0xc00000f8,
        InvalidParameter11 = 0xc00000f9,
        InvalidParameter12 = 0xc00000fa,
        MappedFileSizeZero = 0xc000011e,
        TooManyOpenedFiles = 0xc000011f,
        Cancelled = 0xc0000120,
        CannotDelete = 0xc0000121,
        InvalidComputerName = 0xc0000122,
        FileDeleted = 0xc0000123,
        SpecialAccount = 0xc0000124,
        SpecialGroup = 0xc0000125,
        SpecialUser = 0xc0000126,
        MembersPrimaryGroup = 0xc0000127,
        FileClosed = 0xc0000128,
        TooManyThreads = 0xc0000129,
        ThreadNotInProcess = 0xc000012a,
        TokenAlreadyInUse = 0xc000012b,
        PagefileQuotaExceeded = 0xc000012c,
        CommitmentLimit = 0xc000012d,
        InvalidImageLeFormat = 0xc000012e,
        InvalidImageNotMz = 0xc000012f,
        InvalidImageProtect = 0xc0000130,
        InvalidImageWin16 = 0xc0000131,
        LogonServer = 0xc0000132,
        DifferenceAtDc = 0xc0000133,
        SynchronizationRequired = 0xc0000134,
        DllNotFound = 0xc0000135,
        IoPrivilegeFailed = 0xc0000137,
        OrdinalNotFound = 0xc0000138,
        EntryPointNotFound = 0xc0000139,
        ControlCExit = 0xc000013a,
        PortNotSet = 0xc0000353,
        DebuggerInactive = 0xc0000354,
        CallbackBypass = 0xc0000503,
        PortClosed = 0xc0000700,
        MessageLost = 0xc0000701,
        InvalidMessage = 0xc0000702,
        RequestCanceled = 0xc0000703,
        RecursiveDispatch = 0xc0000704,
        LpcReceiveBufferExpected = 0xc0000705,
        LpcInvalidConnectionUsage = 0xc0000706,
        LpcRequestsNotAllowed = 0xc0000707,
        ResourceInUse = 0xc0000708,
        ProcessIsProtected = 0xc0000712,
        VolumeDirty = 0xc0000806,
        FileCheckedOut = 0xc0000901,
        CheckOutRequired = 0xc0000902,
        BadFileType = 0xc0000903,
        FileTooLarge = 0xc0000904,
        FormsAuthRequired = 0xc0000905,
        VirusInfected = 0xc0000906,
        VirusDeleted = 0xc0000907,
        TransactionalConflict = 0xc0190001,
        InvalidTransaction = 0xc0190002,
        TransactionNotActive = 0xc0190003,
        TmInitializationFailed = 0xc0190004,
        RmNotActive = 0xc0190005,
        RmMetadataCorrupt = 0xc0190006,
        TransactionNotJoined = 0xc0190007,
        DirectoryNotRm = 0xc0190008,
        CouldNotResizeLog = 0xc0190009,
        TransactionsUnsupportedRemote = 0xc019000a,
        LogResizeInvalidSize = 0xc019000b,
        RemoteFileVersionMismatch = 0xc019000c,
        CrmProtocolAlreadyExists = 0xc019000f,
        TransactionPropagationFailed = 0xc0190010,
        CrmProtocolNotFound = 0xc0190011,
        TransactionSuperiorExists = 0xc0190012,
        TransactionRequestNotValid = 0xc0190013,
        TransactionNotRequested = 0xc0190014,
        TransactionAlreadyAborted = 0xc0190015,
        TransactionAlreadyCommitted = 0xc0190016,
        TransactionInvalidMarshallBuffer = 0xc0190017,
        CurrentTransactionNotValid = 0xc0190018,
        LogGrowthFailed = 0xc0190019,
        ObjectNoLongerExists = 0xc0190021,
        StreamMiniversionNotFound = 0xc0190022,
        StreamMiniversionNotValid = 0xc0190023,
        MiniversionInaccessibleFromSpecifiedTransaction = 0xc0190024,
        CantOpenMiniversionWithModifyIntent = 0xc0190025,
        CantCreateMoreStreamMiniversions = 0xc0190026,
        HandleNoLongerValid = 0xc0190028,
        NoTxfMetadata = 0xc0190029,
        LogCorruptionDetected = 0xc0190030,
        CantRecoverWithHandleOpen = 0xc0190031,
        RmDisconnected = 0xc0190032,
        EnlistmentNotSuperior = 0xc0190033,
        RecoveryNotNeeded = 0xc0190034,
        RmAlreadyStarted = 0xc0190035,
        FileIdentityNotPersistent = 0xc0190036,
        CantBreakTransactionalDependency = 0xc0190037,
        CantCrossRmBoundary = 0xc0190038,
        TxfDirNotEmpty = 0xc0190039,
        IndoubtTransactionsExist = 0xc019003a,
        TmVolatile = 0xc019003b,
        RollbackTimerExpired = 0xc019003c,
        TxfAttributeCorrupt = 0xc019003d,
        EfsNotAllowedInTransaction = 0xc019003e,
        TransactionalOpenNotAllowed = 0xc019003f,
        TransactedMappingUnsupportedRemote = 0xc0190040,
        TxfMetadataAlreadyPresent = 0xc0190041,
        TransactionScopeCallbacksNotSet = 0xc0190042,
        TransactionRequiredPromotion = 0xc0190043,
        CannotExecuteFileInTransaction = 0xc0190044,
        TransactionsNotFrozen = 0xc0190045,

        MaximumNtStatus = 0xffffffff
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING

    {

        public UInt16 Length;
        public UInt16 MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr buffer;

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct LUID

    {

        public UInt32 LowPart;
        public UInt32 HighPart;

    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

    private struct SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA

    {

        public UInt32 Size;
        public LUID LoginID;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Username;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING LoginDomain;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING AuthenticationPackage;
        public UInt32 LogonType;
        public UInt32 Session;
        public IntPtr PSiD;
        public UInt64 LoginTime;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING LogonServer;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsDomainName;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Upn;

    }

    private enum SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE : uint

    {

        Interactive = 2,    //The security principal is logging on interactively.
        Network,        //The security principal is logging using a network.
        Batch,          //The logon is for a batch process.
        Service,        //The logon is for a service account.
        Proxy,          //Not supported.
        Unlock,         //The logon is an attempt to unlock a workstation.
        NetworkCleartext,   //The logon is a network logon with cleartext credentials.
        NewCredentials,     // Allows the caller to clone its current token and specify new credentials for outbound connections.
        RemoteInteractive,  // A terminal server session that is both remote and interactive.
        CachedInteractive,  // Attempt to use the cached credentials without going out across the network.
        CachedRemoteInteractive, // Same as RemoteInteractive, except used internally for auditing purposes.
        CachedUnlock      // The logon is an attempt to unlock a workstation.

    }
    public static List<string> GetSessionEnvironmentValue(string variableName, string userFilter="")
    {
        // Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826595/wtsenumeratesessions-hangs-and-never-returns
        // Which appears similar to PS script: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32/LsaEnumerateLogonSessions.html
        
        var outList = new List<string>();
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        DateTime systime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); //win32 systemdate

        UInt64 count;
        IntPtr luidPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out count, out luidPtr);  //gets an array of pointers to LUIDs

        IntPtr iter = luidPtr;      //set the pointer to the start of the array

        for (ulong i = 0; i < count; i++)   //for each pointer in the array
        {
            IntPtr sessionData;

            LsaGetLogonSessionData(iter, out sessionData);
            SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA data = (SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(sessionData, typeof(SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA));

            //if we have a valid logon
            if (data.PSiD != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //get the security identifier for further use
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(data.PSiD);

                //extract some useful information from the session data struct
                var ptrToStringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.Username.buffer);
                if (ptrToStringUni != null)
                {
                    string username = ptrToStringUni.Trim();          //get the account username
                    var toStringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.LoginDomain.buffer);
                    if (toStringUni != null)
                    {
                        string domain = toStringUni.Trim();        //domain for this account  
                        var stringUni = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.AuthenticationPackage.buffer);
                        if (stringUni != null)
                        {
                            string authpackage = stringUni.Trim();    //authentication package
                        }
                        string session = data.Session.ToString();
                        SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE secType = (SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE)data.LogonType;
                        DateTime time = systime.AddTicks((long)data.LoginTime); //get the datetime the session was logged in

                        // get variable
                        var envVarVal = GetUserEnvironmentValue(sid.Value, variableName);

                        // Only add result to list if it meets username filter
                        if (envVarVal!="" && (userFilter=="" || username.ToLower().Contains(userFilter.ToLower())))
                        {
                            outList.Add($"User: {username}, EnvironVar({variableName}): {envVarVal}, SID: {sid.Value}");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            iter = (IntPtr)((int)iter + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LUID)));  //move the pointer forward
            LsaFreeReturnBuffer(sessionData);   //free the SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA memory in the struct
        }
        LsaFreeReturnBuffer(luidPtr);   //free the array of LUIDs

        return outList;
    }

    private static string GetUserEnvironmentValue(string sid, string variableName)
    {
        var envKey = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey($@"{sid}\Environment");
        if (envKey != null)
        {
            var envVarVal = envKey.GetValue(variableName);
            if (envVarVal!=null)
                return envVarVal.ToString();
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

You could call it with a button click in winforms like so:

```
    private void btnOthersEnvVars_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtEnvVar.Text == "")
            throw new Exception("You didn't supply a variable name...");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var sessionInfo in WinApis.GetSessionEnvironmentValue(txtEnvVar.Text)) // you can add a username param as well
        {
            sb.AppendLine(sessionInfo);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

While this didn't give me what I ended up needing, it answers the question as stated.

I ended up going a different route because the environment variable I needed was being set within in a script/batch file or otherwise passed directly to my executable and was not able to be inspected without using some other API's...

If anyone else has a similar situation, I ending up using [Gapotchenko.FX.Diagnostics.Process](https://github.com/gapotchenko/Gapotchenko.FX/tree/master/Source/Gapotchenko.FX.Diagnostics.Process) via nuget package and searching with something similar to this as Admin:

```
        private void btnCurrentProcesses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var procToFind = "Launcher";
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringDictionary env;
        sb.AppendLine($"Session Count{processlist.DistinctBy((x) => x.SessionId).Count()}");
        foreach (Process process in processlist
                                        .Where((p)=>p.ProcessName.ToLower()==procToFind.ToLower())
                                        .OrderBy((x)=>x.SessionId)
                                        .ThenBy((x)=> x.ProcessName))
        {
            if (process!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    env = process.ReadEnvironmentVariables();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    env = new StringDictionary();
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                env = new StringDictionary();
            }                

            sb.AppendLine($"Session: {process.SessionId}, " +
                          $"ProcID: {process.Id}, " +
                          $"Process: {process.ProcessName}, " +
                          $"Env. Var: {env[txtEnvVar.Text]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```